# Flutter: Sending un ascii characters to server using socket.io

Tags: flutter

Im using flutter socket.io to connect to our server. The server doesnt use http protocol etc, straight connect, read and write, so I cant use WebSockets. I have the following:

```
Socket socket;
Uint8List BTBuffer = new Uint8List(10); //a buffer to hold data
Socket.connect("192.168.68.120", 21000);
.then((Socket sock) {
   socket = sock;
   socket.listen(dataHandler); //read data from server (data handler reads the data from server)
   BTBuffer[0]=1;BTBuffer[1]=2;
   socket.write(BTBuffer);
   socket.destroy();
});
```

The above works, but it sends the values as strings and not decimal values. How can I send the values 1 and 2 for example in decimal?  I was assuming there would be a write command pointing to a buffer and number of bytes to send.

Many Thanks
Scott